# Failed to alloc 134217728 bytes for ReadBuffer

Tags: android, material-design, android-virtual-device

am new to android and getting this error every time am running the app
i tried changing the ram allocation of my avd from 512 mb to 1024 mb

```
Failed to alloc 134217728 bytes for ReadBuffer
```

this started happening after i clanged the theme to material.
*my andriodmanifest file*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.shiftind.www.shiftind">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".registration" />
        <activity android:name=".login" />
        <activity android:name=".SignUp" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

*my styles file*

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyThemeNoBar" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: You xml is malformed.

Comment: you are trying to load some huge drawable(s) thats why you are getting that error, check your drawable size.

Comment: Remove the `>` in `<activity android:name=".SplashScreen">`